# How to follow mouse movement the opposite direction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to have a div that follows the mouse coordinates the opposite direction and within a div `.box`. When you move your mouse the red box should move slightly to the opposite direction, so it looks like a kind of parallax effect. Now it will move on your mouse speed and that is not what I want. I would like that the box is move slightly, so you will see the box move a little bit to the opposite direction. And I would like to have align the box to the center of the mouse.

I already have code a script that let the red box follow your mouse movement, but doesn't know how to get above work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.container').on('mousemove',function(e){
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        $('div.box').css({'left': x, 'top': y});
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBrkGa

Answer (score 2):

Try to change `top` to `bottom` and `left` to `right` may solve your problem like,

```
$('div.box').css({'right': x, 'bottom': y});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.container').on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    $('div.box').css({
      'right': x,
      'bottom': y
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  position: absolute;
  right: 200px;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**Updated,** for fixing the box in `100px` range with some delay

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.container').on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var x = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft);
    var y = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
    if(x<100||x>200||y>200||y<100) return false;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('div.box').css({
        'right': x,
        'bottom': y
      }).text(x+','+y);
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  position: absolute;
  right: 200px;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: And how can I slow down the speed of movement of the box, so it will only move within a area of 100 x 100 px and position the box's center to the center of the mouse?

Comment: to position the mouse in the center of the box, you have to substract half the box's height and width from the y and x variables when passed to the box's position

Comment: I missing the part of how to slow down the movement of the box on mouse movement...

Comment: Use `setTimeout(function() {` as used in my second snippet.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('div.container').mousemove(function(e){
  let mouseX = e.pageX;
  let mouseY = e.pageY;

   $(this).children('.box').css({
    'transform': 'translate(' + mouseX / -80 + 'px ,' + mouseY / -80 + 'px)
   })
  });
});
```

The negative numbers will move the object or div (.box) the opposite way of your mouse movement

Comment: Great answer! It might be worth including what makes this answer different to the other answer to this question.